# Check wordpress taxonomy name and put it in conditional statement

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Hi I need to check what is the name of taxonomy on custom post type on wordpress and I did it like this

```
$name = wp_get_post_terms(get_queried_object()->ID,'programmes',array("fields" => "names"));
```

When I do

```
echo $name[0];
```

the name of taxonomy is displayed correctly.
After that I need to check if taxonomy name is Colombia, and if it is then to do something, so when I do that like this

```
if ($name[0] = 'Colombia') {
                echo 'something';
            }
```

the output is word something on every post, not only with post that have taxonomy Colombia. What am I doing wrong. Any help, hint. Thanks.

Comment: You are assigning the value to `$name[0]` with a single equals sign. Try `if ($name[0] === 'Colombia') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `===` operator:

> $a === $b TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

Your example will be:

```
if ($name[0] === 'Colombia') {
     echo 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Comparison Operators "=="

$a == $b (Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type something.)

```
if ($name[0] == 'Colombia') {
                echo 'something';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the comparison operator '`==`'  within if statement.